# Making a "folded list" via python function

Tags: python, function

This is my third time trying to figure this out and as a brand new python user, I really don't understand what my prof is trying to say.

I need to make a function in python that takes a list and "folds it in half", so that the first and last term are added together, the second terma and second to last term, etc. If I have a blank list the output should be blank and if I have an odd-numbered list, the middle term shouldn't be added to anything.

(Original prompt from prof: Prompt: create a function which takes as list as input, and produces a "folded in half" list, by which I mean the first term in the output is the sum of the first and last terms of the input; the second term in the output is the sum of second and second-to-last terms, etc. So an input of [10,2,3,1] would produce [11,5] while an input of [10,2,3] would produce [13,2]. If the input is an empty list, it should return an empty list; if the input is [5] the output should be [5].)

From the helpful guidance of others, this is what I have so far

```
a = [10, 14, 21, 25, 52, 55]
def folded_list(input_list):
    a = input_list
    folded_list_output = [ a[i] + a[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(a) // 2)]
    return folded_list_output
print(folded_list(a))
```

and I thought that it was what my prof wanted. However, he said:
*You have a code snippet that maybe does what you want (using a fancy "list comprehension", that's what that square bracket construction is called, rather than a for-loop), you just need to put it inside a function definition and test that it works. The use of the list comprehension isn't why it's not a function, just the fact that there's no
`def function_name(arguments):`
line in sight.
It's always a good idea to test the "corner cases":  does it do what you want when you give an empty list as input, for example?  What happens for lists with odd numbers of elements?  (Hint: it doesn't do what it is supposed to do, since the middle element is completely dropped.)*

I really don’t get what he’s trying to say - I thought that my

```
def folded_list(input_list):
   a = input_list
   folded_list_output = [ a[i] + a[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(a) // 2)]
   return folded_list_output
```

Was what he was looking for in the arguments section. Does anyone understand what he means and what I should be trying to fix in my code?

Comment: Could you post the instructions posted by the prof so we have a clearer idea from his point of view?

Comment: It seems like you haven't understand the instructions properly, since you mentioned that in case of odd number of elements the middle one dropped, but at the last line of your prof's citation it seems like it shouldn't. there is a mismatch in your definition and his answer.

Comment: Here is the original prompt from him if that helps: Prompt: create a function which takes as list as input, and produces a "folded in half" list, by which I mean the first term in the output is the sum of the first and last terms of the input; the second term in the output is the sum of second and second-to-last terms, etc. So an input of [10,2,3,1] would produce [11,5] while an input of [10,2,3] would produce [13,2]. If the input is an empty list, it should return an empty list; if the input is [5] the output should be [5].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate starting from start(let's say `i`) to the middle and add the `i`th elements from both sides, then return the new list:

```
a = [10, 14, 21, 25, 52, 55]
b = [10, 14, 21, 25, 52, 55, 1]


def folded_list(input_list):
    new_list = []
    l = len(input_list)
    for i in range(l//2):
        new_list.append(input_list[i] + input_list[-i-1])

    if l % 2 != 0:
        return new_list + [input_list[l//2]]
    return new_list


print(folded_list(a))  # [65, 66, 46]
print(folded_list(b))  # [11, 69, 73, 25]
```

Comment: Hey @S3DEV I corrected the logic now. Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

> You have a code snippet that maybe does what you want

You probably sent your professor *just the list-comprehension*. They wanted you to send a *function*.

> (using a fancy "list comprehension", that's what that square bracket construction is called, rather than a for-loop),

Pretty self-explanatory

> you just need to put it inside a function definition and test that it works.
> The use of the list comprehension isn't why it's not a function, just the fact that there's no
> `def function_name(arguments):`
> line in sight.

`def function_name(argument1, argument2, ...):` is what makes the code inside that block a function. If you submit this:

```
def folded_list(input_list):
   a = input_list
   folded_list_output = [ a[i] + a[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(a) // 2)]
   return folded_list_output
```

then `folded_list` is the function that takes a single argument `input_list`.

Since you have some background in FORTRAN, a subroutine or function in FORTRAN would be classified as a function in Python. Remember how you need to say `function myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3) result(answer)` in FORTRAN to define a function? You need to say `def myfunc(arg1, arg2, arg3)` in Python. In FORTRAN, a function *must* return something but a subroutine *can't*. In Python, a function may or may not return something. That's pretty much the only difference at the novice level.

> It's always a good idea to test the "corner cases"

Corner cases are cases that you expect will break your code (but ideally shouldn't). Testing corner cases is how you can ensure that your code is robust and won't break when it receives a funky but valid input.

> does it do what you want when you give an empty list as input, for example?

Does it?

```
folded_list([])
# Output: []
```

Certainly looks like it

> What happens for lists with odd numbers of elements?  (Hint: it doesn't do what it is supposed to do, since the middle element is completely dropped.)

```
folded_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
# Output: [6, 6]
```

Hey! This doesn't look right! What happened to the `3` in the middle of the list?

---

Now since the whole point of this exercise is for you to learn, I'm not going to *give* you the code you need. Here's an algorithm you could use though:

- For a list with an odd number of elements, let's say 5, `len(list) = 5`
- So `len(list) // 2 = 2`
- Indices 0 and 1 need to be added to 3 and 4
- Index 2 needs to be left alone (hey look, `2 = len(list) // 2`)
- Iterate over the first half of the list

  - If the current index less than `len(list)//2`, append `list[index] + list[-index]` to the new list (A negative index just tells Python to take that element counting backwards instead of forwards, so `list[-2]` would give you the second-to-last element)
  - If the index is equal to `len(list)//2`, append `list[index]`

Does this work when `len(list)` is an even number? If it doesn't work with even-sized lists, can you come up with an algorithm that does work for even *and* odd sized lists? Or is the only option to have an `if` condition to check the list size, and then run one algorithm for even-sizes and another for odd-sizes? That's an exercise for you!

Also note: when I was a beginner, I found it more intuitive to first write out the whole loop, and then condense it down into a list-comprehension if possible.
This list comprehension:

```
folded_list_output = [ a[i] + a[-(i + 1) ] for i in range( len(a) // 2)]
```

is easier to understand (or at least was, for me many years ago) if written like so:

```
folded_list_output = []
for i in range(len(a) // 2):
    elem1 = a[i]
    elem2 = a[-(i + 1)] 

    folded_list_output.append(elem1 + elem2)
```

Comment: Nice breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I wanted to give this a try using `zip`, list comprehension and slice notation.  Personally, this is more logical - but maybe that's just my lopsided brain.

It looks something like this mess:

```
def folded(lst) -> list:
    """Fold a list by summing opposite ends."""
    r = [a+b for a, b in zip(lst, lst[::-1])][:(len(lst)//2)+1]
    if len(lst) % 2 != 0:
        r = r[:-1] + [r[-1:][0]//2]
    else:
        r = r[:-1]
    return r
```

Output:

```
l = [2]
>>> [2]

l = [2, 5]
>>> [7]

l = [2, 5, 8]
>>> [10, 5]

l = [2, 5, 8, 10]
>>> [12, 13]

l = [2, 5, 8, 10, 12]
>>> [14, 15, 8]
```

Comment: How about a one-liner? No `zip`, so no making copies of lists but yes `enumerate` and ternary ops: `[(a + lst[-i-1]) // (2 if i == len(lst)//2 else 1) for i, a in enumerate(lst)][:len(lst)//2 + (1 if len(lst) % 2 else 0)]`

Comment: Or using bool-int casts: `[(a + lst[-i-1]) // (1 + (i == len(lst)//2)) for i, a in enumerate(lst)][:len(lst)//2 + (len(lst) % 2)]`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - Love it mate, thanks!  Will def mess around with these.